why printf 'helloworld' {1..$nlines}; does not work?
How can I do this in bash with printf:
Printing n times the same line using as n times a variable inside printf brackets?
nlines=5; 
printf 'helloworld' {1..$nlines};


You can't use variables in bash's brace expansion. Use $(seq ...) or a for (( ... )) loop like in the dupe
